# best practice for rest api login resource

Tags: laravel, restful-authentication

I want to start a rest API project with `laravel` using `JWT` as authentication system.
There is a package for django rest framework for using `JWT` authentication. In `djangorestframework-simplejwt` documentation, two path is added to `urls.py`: `api/token/ and api/token/refresh/`
To authorizing users which resource is the best one: `api/v1/login or api/v1/token` ?

Comment: I would say, the one that makes sense to you or to your app. I don't think there's a common practice on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use JWT for your API authentication , i will suggest to use following package 
https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/

Comment: Isn't it in RC since years? There's also [sprocketbox/laravel-jwt](https://github.com/sprocketbox/laravel-jwt) which has been released recently and an another one which is important to mention even if it's **NOT** JWT; Laravel will very soon release [laravel/airlock](https://github.com/laravel/airlock)